# How Elsa workflow to work in Blazor WebAssembly ASP.Net Core Hosting?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, elsa-workflows

I Have 3 Prject: My.Clint, My.Server, My.Shared in WASM.
How to apply Elsa 2.x or Elsa 3.x?

The example: ElsaDashboard.Samples.BlazorServer or ElsaDashboard.Samples.BlazorWasm at https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core is not same structure (Client+Server+Shared).

I need example for WASM, and that can run web pages, Elsa dashboard and excecute Elsa workflow by Http in same IP:Port address Server.